# jvm heap size error while making build from maven

Tags: java, maven-3

I am making an ear of my web application which consist of multiple projects within i.e. around 23 projects out of which some are java projects and some are dynamic web projects. When I am making the EAR from RAD, it is generated successfully but when I try to make EAR from MAVEN, it is throwing heap size problem. When I reduce the number of projects in `POM.xm`l i.e. from 23 to 12 EAR is successfully generated but increasing the number of projects brings the same error of heap size.

If I set the environment variable `MAVEN_OPTS = -Xmx1024M`, it's not working. My PC RAM is 2 GB and when I try to set `MAVEN_OPTS = -Xmx2048M`, it is throwing an error as it cannot reserve this much space for JVM.

I have jdk 1.7 and maven 3.

Please do suggest.

Comment: You are using maven from cmd or any IDE ?

Comment: both tries were made on the same OS, right? no change of environment?

Comment: from cmd using the command mvn -e install

Comment: Can you say at which goal or which Maven phase the OOM Error is thrown?

Comment: Perhaps you need to export that environment variable since multiple things are forked off of the parent process during the course of the build... if you're just doing MAVEN_OPTS=blah it likely won't effect anything.

Answer (score 4):

We have the same problem with our multi-module project. There seems to be a memory leak in the compiler or the compiler plug-in. So when Maven starts to build the EAR it consumes too much memory to build the EAR project, too. However you can advise the compiler to run in a seperate process so this problem does not occur (see [Maven docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/compile-with-memory-enhancements.html)):

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <fork>true</fork>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: Hi could you please tell where should i include this code.....i added it in settings.xml but it didnot worked there.

Comment: It has to be added in the <build> section of your pom.xml. If you follow the links to the Maven docs you can see the complete structure.

Comment: I tried using this but its not working then also.....throwing the same error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Suggestions:

- Get a machine with more memory.
- Shutdown your IDE before running the build.
- Try increasing the heap size to some number *between* 1Gb and 2Gb.
- Try building the component projects one at a time in the right order, using the `install` goal.  (The chances are that the problem is due to Maven keeping too much stuff in memory between building the individual projects.)

It is also worth looking into *why* it can't allocate 2Gb of heap space.  It might be an issue with swap space, or it might be the 32bit Windows 2Gb limit which can be worked around.

And Roland's idea is a good one too.